# jQuery UI position stay on element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I position an element to the left on a textbox with jQuery UI [.position()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) at the bottom of my page.

Now I'm loading my content via AJAX. The header and the footer doesn't change, only the content in the middle.

So the document height changes but the element is still located absolute at the position where the textbox was before the document height changed.

Anyone who can give me a hint, that the positioned element stays with the "mother element" when the doc height changes?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Here is an **example**:

http://jsfiddle.net/u9HNW/

I know that I could remove `position: absolute` from `#pos`, but I need to move an absolute positioned div with it's content.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want that the ajax loaded content forces the abs positioned item to move, or not?

Comment: Exactly, I want the positioned item to move.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle as an example. Look at my edit.

Comment: I guess you'd have to re-call the position method in the success handler of the ajax request...

Comment: I also thought about this, but is there a way to move the element while sliding?

Comment: I went around this by fading the element out when loading content and position it again when the document has it's full height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pos {
    position: relative;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

works in the jsfiddle

Comment: Any absolutely positioned element inside a relatively positioned element will move with the element. i.e., it is absolutely positioned in relation to any parent with an absolute or relative position.